# C# look for a value in Excel and do something with it

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to look through a spreadsheet and find the value 'description'. Ultimately, I want to find a number of values that are actually going to be column headers but they dont always reside in the same cells so need to search for them.
Currently I'm just trying to find 'description' and turn that cell red so I know finding it right however, I get red lines on 'missing' and I'm not sure why:

```
        Excel.Range currentFind = null;
        Excel.Range firstFind = null;

        Excel.Range columnHeaders = oWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "A20");
        currentFind = columnHeaders.Find("Description", missing,
                    Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                    Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false,
                    missing, missing);

        while (currentFind != null)
        {
            // Keep track of the first range you find. 
            if (firstFind == null)
            {
                firstFind = currentFind;
            }

            // If you didn't move to a new range, you are done.
            else if (currentFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1)
                  == firstFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
            {
                break;
            }

            currentFind.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            currentFind.Font.Bold = true;

            currentFind = columnHeaders.FindNext(currentFind);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do the red line says on `missing`? Did you declare it as a variable and initialize it?

Comment: the name 'missing' does not exist in the current context - it came from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-search-for-text-in-worksheet-ranges?view=vs-2019

Comment: Try changing `missing` to `null`.

Comment: Looks like it prefers null

Comment: Is there a solid reason you need to use the Excel interop libraries? There are tools like EPPlus and ClosedXML which make interacting with an Excel file much easier.

Comment: I've only ever used interop - open to better suggestions :) I'm trying to extract data from spreadsheet and put it in a table but the spreadsheet isnt always formatted the same so I need to look for key words that will be the column headers. Sorry bit off topic perhaps